# Filtering pg_dump with only INSERT lines and changing table name using awk

Tags: mysql, regex, bash, postgresql, awk

I want to create a bash script that does a pg_dump of only INSERT lines and changes the table title in the INSERT line.

I have the following bash script:

```
#!bin/bash

#Create temp files to store the PSQL dump
DUMPFILE='poops.dump.sql' || (echo "make sql dump file failed" 1>&2; exit 1)
TMPFILE=`mktemp` || (echo "mktemp failed" 1>&2; exit 1)

#Tables to dump: api_order, poops_order_dates, poops_price
#Dump as INSERT queries statements
pg_dump --username="poops" --host="localhost" \
 --table="api_order" --table="poops_order_dates" --table="poops_price" \
 --no-password --column-inserts \
 --data-only "poops" | \
 awk '/^INSERT/ {i=1} {if(i) print}' \
 > "$TMPFILE" \
 || (echo "pg_dump failed" 1>&2; exit 1)

(echo "start transaction; truncate table api_order; "; \
 echo "truncate table poops_order_dates; "; \
 echo "truncate table poops_price; "; \
 cat "$TMPFILE"; echo 'commit;' ) \
> "$DUMPFILE" \
|| (echo "parsing dump file failed" 1>&2; exit 1)

rm "$TMPFILE"
```

It removes all the junk before the first INSERT INTO line, however there is still the following stuff after all the INSERT INTO queries:

```
--
-- Name: api_order_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE SET; Schema: public; Owner: poops
--

SELECT pg_catalog.setval('api_order_id_seq', 33146, true);


--
-- Data for Name: poops_order_dates; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: poops
--



--
-- Name: poops_order_dates_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE SET; Schema: public; Owner: poops
--

SELECT pg_catalog.setval('poops_order_dates_id_seq', 1, false);


--
-- Data for Name: poops_price; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: poops
--



--
-- Name: poops_price_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE SET; Schema: public; Owner: poops
--

SELECT pg_catalog.setval('poops_price_id_seq', 1, false);


--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

How do I write the following awk line:

```
awk '/^INSERT/ {i=1} {if(i) print}' \
```

To make it so that it only outputs the INSERT INTO queries, and changes api_order to api_order_test.

I did try:

```
awk '/^INSERT/ {gsub("INSERT INTO api_order", "INSERT INTO api_order_test", $0); print $0}' \
```

But because of print $0, it cuts off part of the query where it starts on a new line.  I need it to filter for, output and change only

```
 "INSERT INTO api_order .... );\r"
```

I believe at the end it is a carriage return (\r) or does pg_dump output each INSERT INTO query with a \n at the end?

Raw SQL Dump:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;

--
-- Data for Name: api_order; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: poops
--

INSERT INTO api_order (id, order type, …'', 0, NULL);
INSERT INTO api_order (id, order type, …'', 0, NULL);
INSERT INTO api_order (id, order type, …'', 0, NULL);
INSERT INTO api_order (id, order type, …'', 0, NULL);
INSERT INTO api_order (id, order type, …'', 0, NULL);


--
-- Name: api_order_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE SET; Schema: public; Owner: poops
--

SELECT pg_catalog.setval('api_order_id_seq', 33294, true);

--
-- Data for Name: hoops_price; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: poops
--

--
-- Name: hoops_price_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE SET; Schema: public; Owner: poops
--

SELECT pg_catalog.setval('hoops_price_id_seq', 1, false);

--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

Comment: If everything you don't want to print comes after everything you do want to print, you can "turn off" printing in the same way you turn it on. Something like `/^INSERT/ {i=1} /^SELECT/ {i=0} i`.  (Note that the trailing `i` is equivalent to your `{ if (i) print }`)  If you're input is more complicated or there are other considerations, please post a representative sample of the input to awk and your expected output.

Comment: it could help if we can see the orginal source (before your awk) and desired final output (not neede to give 1000 lines, only representatives )

Comment: Thank you Jas that helps.  Only the select statements had to be removed to make it functional.  The comments did not need to be touched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everything you don't want to print comes after everything you do want to print, you can "turn off" printing in the same way you turn it on. Something like `/^INSERT/ {i=1} /^SELECT/ {i=0} i`.  (Note that the trailing `i` is equivalent to your `{ if (i) print }`)  If you're input is more complicated or there are other considerations, please post a representative sample of the input to awk and your expected output.
                    – jas